# Execute mediawiki extension job periodically

Tags: mediawiki, jobs, wikipedia

I'm developing an extension for mediawiki. My extension needs to execute some database updating periodically (e.g. every 30 mins).
Reading mediawiki manual I found there is a job queue implemented, but it does not have support for scheduling.

Is there any way to set a mediawiki extension job to execute periodically?

Answer (score 2):

This is not what a job queue is for; it is to run a task as soon as there are free resources. Create a [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Writing_maintenance_scripts) and use cron to run it periodically.

Answer (score 0):

The job works thanks wiki visits. Each **n** visits, a job is executed (**n** being configured in your LocalSettings.php).

It is probably not what you are looking for, but if you really want to purge this queue every 30 minutes, you can still use a cron job. For instance :

```
30 * * * * php ./maintenance/runJobs.php
```

Based on your short elements, I would propose instead to configure cron to execute one of the scripts of your extension, and explain the set up in your install documentation.